# How do I make a graceful shutdown (with zero replicas)?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am running a three node (elasticsearch) cluster currently with `index.number_of_replicas: 0`. I'd like to bring one of the node down for maintenance. Do I have any options to do this without increasing `number_of_replicas`?

Shutdown API does not seem to rebalance the shards before shutdown of the node. So, it looks like I need to use the cluster reroute API to manually move the shards to another node. Doing so would like rebalance other shards back to my node, so I guess I would need to somehow rebalance the cluster. Is there any better option that this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You can decommission a node by telling the cluster to exclude it from
>   allocation. (From the documentation
>   [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-cluster.html))
>
> ```
> curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -d '{
>   "transient" :{
>       "cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._ip" : "10.0.0.1"
>    }
> }';echo
> ```
>
> This will cause Elasticsearch to allocate the shards on that node to
>   the remaining nodes, without the state of the cluster changing to
>   yellow or red (even if you have replication 0).
>
> Once all the shards have been reallocated you can shutdown the node
>   and do whatever you need to do there. Once you're done, include the
>   node for allocation and Elasticsearch will rebalance the shards again.

Answer copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/23905040/260805